# Bitget working with large inputs?

Tags: matlab, bit, sparse-matrix

The default type [is](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/bitget.html) `uint64` but the below apparently requires larger support where you can see that the number `536870915` (100000000000000000000000000011 in binary, 30 bits' length) is not supported by the above bitget command. So

> **How to get bitget command working with large inputs like the below?**

**Input**

```
hhhh=sparse([],[],[],2^40+1,1); 
hhhh(536870915)=1; 
bitget(str2num(dec2bin(find(hhhh)-1)),2,'uint64')
```

**Output**

```
Error using bitget
Double inputs must have integer values in the range of ASSUMEDTYPE.
```

Comment: The argument yo `bitget` here is not 536870915; it's approximately 10^29

Comment: @LuisMendo I cannot understand, am I doing the conversion wrong?

Comment: Maybe just `bitget(find(hhhh)-1,2)` (or `bitget(find(hhhh)-1,2,'uint64')`)?

Comment: The result of `str2num(dec2bin(find(hhhh)-1)` is a number, whose *decimal* representation only contains 1 and 0.

Comment: @LuisMendo does that actualy mean something different, where do you specify the base? Look 100 could be in the base of 10, 2 or something else.

Comment: @hhh: You can't change the base of an double / integer variable in matlab. Matlab always uses base 2, but displays base 10. Try `bitget` for some small values, you will notice how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass the output of `dec2bin(find(hhhh)-1)` to `str2num`. This directly converts the string of ones and zeros into a double: `9.999999999999999e+28`. I'm guessing that's not what you want.

If you're just trying to get the second bit of `536870915`, why not use:

```
bitget(find(hhhh)-1,2,'uint64')
```

On the other hand, I think that you could also use this (probably slower, but maybe it'll work with the rest of your code if you're already converting to string representation):

```
b = dec2bin(find(hhhh)-1);
str2double(b(end-1))
```

It seems like you're trying to combine two approaches.

Comment: Yes but where do you specify the base? Does teh bitget assume the base 2 by default?

Comment: @hhh, as the name says, it is getting bits. that kind of implies base 2 :-)

Comment: @hhh: You don't get to specify this. `bitget` is working on the underlying binary (as @A.Donda said) data that is used to represent the values. Setting the `ASSUMEDTYPE` only casts the values to another integer type – values are preserved except in the case of over/underflow. Doubles (only integer-valued ones are permitted) are mapped to naturally to `unint64` values by default